# Can't add a 'click' eventListener if a 'mousemove' listener was added earlier

Tags: javascript, events

I'm attaching an element to the mouse when it moves using:

```
let follower = document.getElementById('followMouse');
        const onMouseMove = (e) => {
            follower.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
            follower.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        }
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
```

Later when I try to do a 'click' event listener, the click doesn't fire:

```
let myElem = document.createElement('div');

myElem.classList.add('myDiv');

myElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('click in the myElem');
        })

document.body.appendChild(myElem);
```

But it fires if I comment out the earlier mousemove event listener.

Why does the mousemove event listener not allow me to add a click listener later?

Snippet for testing:

```js
let follower = document.getElementById('followMouse');
const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  follower.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  follower.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

let myElem = document.createElement('div');

myElem.classList.add('myDiv');

myElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('click in the myElem'); //not working
})

document.body.appendChild(myElem);
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#followMouse {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    .myDiv {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    
    #followMouse {
      position: absolute;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="followMouse">Follow mouse</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text that follows the mouse cursor covers the div you are trying to click.

Add `pointer-events: none` to fix the issue

```js
let follower = document.getElementById('followMouse');
const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  follower.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  follower.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

let myElem = document.createElement('div');

myElem.classList.add('myDiv');

myElem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert('click in the myElem'); //not working
})

document.body.appendChild(myElem);
```

```css
.myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#followMouse {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="followMouse">Follow mouse</div>
```